# Browser settings for large web pages?

Tags: firefox, memory, browser

I use Firefox and Chrome to download web pages that are pretty large (also containing thousands of thumbnail images that are also saved to HDD), 
when page is more than 30-40MB browser becomes very slow and sometimes crashes. Is there a way to change settings so that browser can deal with large web pages? Also if there is some other browser that is better to deal with large pages?
Some pages that I need to save are about 100MB.
Using win10 64bit, 3.6ghz intel CPU, 8GB RAM, SSD drive lot of free space, as soon as browser uses more than 1.5GB RAM it becomes very slow even though there is more RAM available. Also swap file is pretty large.

Comment: 64-bit Firefox? Have you used Developer Tools to watch what is happening on page load?

Comment: From tests that I read 64-bit Firefox is slower than 32bit.
I had better experience with Chromium, in terms of stability than with Firefox. Only it gets very slow when saving page on HDD, is there a way to fix this,how to force Chromium to use more RAM?